# Series expansion of $E_1(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105867/integrals-int-limits-0t-eu-log-u-operatorname-d-u-and-int-limits-0?rq=1) there is a series expansion derived for $\int_0^t e^{-u} \log u du = - (E_1(t)+\gamma+\log(t)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{kk!} + (1-e^t)\log(t)$. Yet one finds in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) that there is no such extra term $(1-e^t)\log(t)$. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int\limits_0^t e^{-u} \log(u) \, du=-E_1(t)-e^{-t} \log (t)-\gamma=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{k\, k!}+\left(1-e^{-t}\right) \log(t)\tag{1}$$

which is consistent with

$$E_1(t)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{k\, k!}-\log (t)-\gamma\tag{2}.$$